# Terraform: Assign resource attribute to resource argument using If/Else pattern

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using the [IF/ELSE pattern](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9) in Terraform to build a NIC with or without a public IP.  The problem comes when assigning the NIC.  I can't find a technique that lets me choose the resource that was used to create the NIC (with or without public IP).  Using ternary operations fail because one of the resources doesn't exist.  Putting the resources in a list doesn't interpolate.  How do I assign the correct resource output?

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
    count                        = "${var.assign_public_ip}"
    name                         = "${format("${var.name}-pip%02d", count.index)}"
    location                     = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name          = "${var.resource_group_name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "static"

    tags {
        environment = "${var.resource_group_name}"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic_with_public_ip" {
    count               = "${var.assign_public_ip}"
    name                = "${format("${var.name}-nic%02d", count.index)}"
    location            = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "ip_cfg"
        subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet_id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id}"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
    count               = "${1 - var.assign_public_ip}"
    name                = "${format("${var.name}-nic%02d", count.index)}"
    location            = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "ip_cfg"
        subnet_id                     = "${var.subnet_id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "centos" {
    count                 = "${var.count}"
    name                  = "${format("${var.name}%02d", count.index)}"
    location              = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name   = "${var.resource_group_name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${var.assign_public_ip == 1 ? azurerm_network_interface.nic_with_public_ip.id : azurerm_network_interface.nic.id }"]
    vm_size               = "${var.size}"
    delete_os_disk_on_termination = true
    delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "OpenLogic"
        offer     = "CentOS"
        sku       = "7.3"
        version   = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
        name              = "${format("${var.name}-osdisk%02d", count.index)}"
        caching           = "ReadWrite"
        create_option     = "FromImage"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "${format("${var.name}%02d", count.index)}"
        admin_username = "${var.admin_user}"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = true
        ssh_keys = {
            path = "/home/${var.admin_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
            key_data = "${var.ssh_key}"
    }
  }

  tags {
      environment = "${var.name}"
  }
}
```

This fails with the following error:
    Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

```
* module.jumphost.azurerm_virtual_machine.centos: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.jumphost.azurerm_virtual_machine.centos: Resource 'azurerm_network_interface.nic' not found for variable 'azurerm_network_interface.nic.id'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "splat expression" can be used to get a list of the values of an attribute for of the instances created from a resource block with `count`:

```
azurerm_network_interface.nic_with_public_ip.*.id
```

This returns an empty list when `count = 0`. In a situation like this where at all times there is a total of one across all counts, it's possible to exploit this with `concat` to select whichever one is present:

```
network_interface_ids = "${concat(azurerm_network_interface.nic_with_public_ip.*.id, azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id)}"
```

Since `network_interface_ids` is already a list, we can just assign directly the result of `concat` here. Due to how `count` is being assigned on these resources, we know that this list will always have exactly one elements, which achieves the desired result of selecting the one that is active.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the help.  I made a minor edit to the assignment, making it a list.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In resource `azurerm_virtual_machine`, change to `azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id`

Comment: Can you be more explicit please?  I tried your answer two ways, neither worked.  Changing the line to     
`network_interface_ids = ["${var.assign_public_ip == 1 ? azurerm_network_interface.nic_with_public_ip.*.id :azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id }"]  ` or `network_interface_ids = ["${var.assign_public_ip == 1 ? azurerm_network_interface.nic_with_public_ip.id :azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id }"]` both gave errors